# How to use Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following tables in in DB:
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNab3.png)

and want to have hibernate @Entity **ExchangeRates** like followng POJO:

```
class ExchangeRates{
    List<Currency> currencies;
}

class Currency{
    Long Id;
    String name;
    List<Rate> exchangeRates;
}

class Rate{
    Currency currency;
    BibDecimal rate;
}
```

can any advice me how to do this with hibernate annotations?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two `Entities` with a `ManyToMany` relationship you will have a JoinTable that references both.

The Table would e.g. look like this:

```
Name: EX_CUR
Column 1:CUR_ID
Column 2:EX_ID
```

And the Entities like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="currencies_fixed_exchange_rates")
class ExchangeRates{

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
      name="EX_CUR",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CUR_ID", 
      referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EX_ID", 
      referencedColumnName="ID"))
    List<Currency> currencies;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="currencies")
class Currency{

    @Id
    Long Id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="currencies")
    List<Rate> exchangeRates;
}

@Entity
@Table
class Rate{

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    Currency currency;

    @Column
    BigDecimal rate;
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. Isn't it possible to do this only with this two tables I already have?

Comment: The Problem is the ManyToMany-Relationship. The relationships that are connecting different instances of the same entity have to know of each. An entity cannot know of other entities that it is not supposed to know.

Like
If you are have 3 cars that you are allowed to drive and another person is also allowed to drive two of them plus an additional car that you are not allowed to drive. If you only have to tables how do you plan to separate these?